# Determining factorial of a number

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this factorial function to work. Here's my code now.

```
  var x = prompt("Enter a number"); {
    function fact(x) {
      if (x < 0) {
        return ("Enter a positive integer");
        }
      else {
        return (x * fact(x-1))
      }
    }
  }
  var result = fact(x)
  document.write("The factorial of" + x + "is" + result);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like you're still multiplying numbers when x = 0. Also, what are your brackets for after the first `var` line?

Comment: yes, return result for your base case (x=0), and it'll be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of factorial is wrong. The traditional recursive definition of factorial is:

```
F(x) => x == 1 ? 1 : x * F(x-1)
```

Or you can use the iterative definition

```
F(x) => var i = 1; for (j = 1..x) i = i * j
```

In javascript, the recursive version would be:

```
function factorial (x) {
    if (x == 1) return x;
    return x * factorial(x-1);
}
```

The iterative version would be:

```
function factorial (x) {
    var result = 1;
    for (var y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
        result = result * y;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can add the negative number check in the above functions. But in my opinion that would obscure the purpose of the function (which is to implement the traditional definition of factorial). A better approach is to move the negative number `if()` check outside of the factorial function. The `if (x < 0)` check has its own purpose that is separate from calculating factorials: input validation.

Answer (score 2):

your base case is wrong for a recursive factorial. change it to

```
function fact(x) {
    if (x <= 1) {
        return 1
    }
    else {
        return (x * fact(x-1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In every recursive function, there exists a stopping condition (in your case its `if(x<=1)`) without which, the function would go to infinite recursion. You had not added that stopping condition. Following is the working updated program:

```
var x = prompt("Enter a number"); {
    function fact(x) {
      if (x < 0) {
        return ("Enter a positive integer");
      }
      else if(x <=1){
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        return (x * fact(x-1))
      }
    }
  }
  var result = fact(x)
  document.write("The factorial of " + x + " is " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to fixing the flawed algorithm, I recommend moving your prompt into its own function for separation of concerns.

I also like the idea of using a `while` statement for this as well as doing a `parseInt` on the input:

```js
function fact(x) {
    while (x > 1) {
        return (x * fact(x-1));
    }
    return x;
}
function doFact() {
    var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a positive integer"));
    if (x < 1) {
        doFact();
    } else {
        var result = fact(x);
        alert("The factorial of " + x + " is " + result);   
    }
}
doFact();
```